# UI freezes when using AFNetworking 2.0 in iOS 6?

Tags: iphone, ios6, afnetworking-2

We recently migrated to `AFNetworking 2.0` in our project. It works fine in iOS 7 but in case of iOS 6 UI freezes because of it. It seems Something went wrong with Operations. Any thoughts on it?
When i Checked the debug console :-

SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:didCommitLoadForFrame:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode

Comment: Any crash logs??? Any code??? Do you have anything to share??? Voting to close due to lack of information to replicate.

Comment: Its not crashing. App got hanged. When i Checked the debug console :-SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:didCommitLoadForFrame:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode

Comment: What kind of freezes? When data is downloading/being saved UI freezes for some seconds or freezes and never unfreezes (needs app restart)?  How do You know the problem is in Operations? How are You using AFNetworking - can You explain more?

Comment: I have edited my earlier comment posted the warning message that i am getting in debug console.

Comment: For example - I also encountered App hanging (needed app restart then) - but in that case - I was downloading / saving / updating Core data database in background thread, but simultaneously without limiting task number (by task I mean downloading data, then validating, then saving. so- multiple tasks, multiple downloads/saving at the same time). Then I rewrote my downloader, so that only one download task at a time. Once data has been downloaded/validated/saved - it starts downloading data for next task. And App stopped freezing randomly.

Comment: It works perfectly fine in iOS7 only in case of iOS 6 we are facing this issue and earlier Afnetwoirking 1.0 is works well with our project.

Comment: Operations are not getting called after adding to the operationQueue.

Comment: If You insist that it's AFNetworking problem, then I suggest You go to the core place: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues search if there is any similar issue, if not, create one! Good luck!